# React Native: Refresh Control error - 'TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to link a React Native `<RefreshControl>` component to my app in such a way that it triggers a new dispatch to my redux store. However upon scrolling down to trigger the refresh the loading wheel briefly spins before returning the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...cards.map...')`

My component code and redux functions are below:

**Component Code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, ScrollView, RefreshControl} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchBalanceActionCreator, fetchPriceActionCreator} from './actions';
import ItemCard from './ItemCard';

class StoreItems extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          directionalLockEnabled={true}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={this.props.refreshing}
              onRefresh={() => {
                console.log('+++ onRefresh');
                this.props.fetchData(this.props.cards);
              }}
            />
          }
          horizontal={false}>

          {ITEMS.map(item => {
            return (
              <ItemCard name={item.name} price={item.price} qty={item.qty} />
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(
    'Data +++ refreshing',
    state.itemPrice.isFetching || state.cardBalance.isFetching,
  );
  return {
    refreshing: state.itemPrice.isFetching || state.cardBalance.isFetching,
    cards: state.cards,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchData: cards => {
  console.log('fetchData1');
      dispatch(fetchBalanceActionCreator(cards));
      dispatch(fetchPriceActionCreator(cards));
  console.log('fetchData2');
    },
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(StoreItems);
```

**Redux Functions**

```
function fetchPriceActionCreator(items) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestItemPriceActionCreator());

    const reqs = items.map(item => {
      return getItemPrice(item.itemNumber);
    });

    return Promise.all(reqs).then(res => {
      dispatch(receiveItemPriceActionCreator(res));
    });
  };
}

function fetchBalanceActionCreator(cards) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestBalanceActionCreator());

    const reqs = cards.map(card => {
      const cardType = card.cardType.toLowerCase();
      const cardNumber = card.cardNumber;
      return getBalances(cardType, cardNumber);
    });

    return Promise.all(reqs)
      .then(balances => {
        dispatch(receiveBalanceActionCreator(balances));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
}
```

EDIT:

The `getBalances` and `getPrices` functions are both making API calls.

Most of the data fetched from these calls is displayed in child components/elsewhere in the app, but I want to be able to refresh on this particular screen.

I have added a number of `console.log`s throughout the code, the results are as follows:

1. `+++ onRefresh` displays in the console
2. `fetchData1` follows immediately after
3. `data +++ refreshing` is then displayed, I have noticed occasionally
   it shows a value of `true`, and occasionally a value of `false`
4. `fetchData2` is never logged to the console.

The error screen in the app simulator references the line with             `dispatch(fetchBalanceActionCreator(cards));` from the StoreItems component, in addition to the `return function(dispatch) {`line from the Redux action creator file.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the getBalance function:

```
    async function getBalances(cardType, card) {
  cardType = cardType.toLowerCase();
  const balance = await balanceRequestor[cardType](card);

  return {
    cardId: cardType,
    card: card,
    balance: balance,
  };
}
```

Depending on the card type, `getBalance` will then trigger a function fetches data from an API and looks like so:

```
    export async function getCard1Balance(card) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.exampleapi.com/${card}`);

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

All of these functions work fine upon loading and navigating the app, it only seems to be when using the `RefreshControl` that the `undefined is not a function` is shown.

Comment: can you give a bit context where the error is happening? also where is `getBalances` coming from? maybe try some console logs to identify where and what the error exactly is

Comment: I've edited the initial post to include additional context and results of my console logs. Let me know if that is sufficient

Comment: can you show the declaration of `getBalances` im trying to work out which function is not a function

Comment: Have made new edits with more information on `getBalances`

Comment: are you able to keep commenting out and see when the error goes away? or create this on codesandbox so I can have a play